# UICollectionView scrolling dilemma

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uiscrollview, uicollectionview

I have searched for an answer but haven't found one to fit my specific issue, and a swift solution at that. I have a UICollectionView when scrolled down doesn't snap and fit the bottom frame as it should. Here is what I mean:

Here is the top of my CollectionView, perfectly placed, and when scrolled up or down, snaps back into position:

[image]

Now here is the bottom of my CollectionView, as you can see it hangs off the bottom inset as it shouldn't:

[image]

I basically want it to stop scrolling at the same position as the top does. How do I achieve this? here is my existing code:

```
var cellHeight: CGFloat = 140
var cellWidth: CGFloat = 120
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.tabBarController?.tabBar.hidden = true;

    collectionView.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGrayColor()

    layout.minimumInteritemSpacing = 0
    layout.minimumLineSpacing = 10

    layout.sectionInset.bottom = 10
    layout.sectionInset.right = 4
    layout.sectionInset.top = 10
    layout.sectionInset.left = 4

    collectionView.contentInset.bottom = 10
    collectionView.contentInset.top = 10
    self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = false

    layout.itemSize = CGSizeMake(cellWidth, cellHeight)

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to adjust the inset values in below way.Hope it will help you.

```
    collectionView.contentInset.bottom = 10
collectionView.contentInset.top = 10
    self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = false
```

Comment: so all i did was add the `self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = false` method since i already have `layout.sectionInset.bottom = 10` in my code

Comment: now now it fixed the issue of the bottom, but now the top of my collection view is pushed up behind the navigation bar

Comment: didn't fix the issue. check updated question to see the code i have in my controller at the moment

Comment: Adjust the value of top inset and check.It gives you better solution.

Comment: yeah i was doing that but when i switch the orientation of the device, the top of the collection view is at a different position. it doesn't equal out. in portrait, the top is hidden behind the nav bar, in landscape, its exactly where i want it.

Comment: If you have orientation changes adjust the insets in this method.     override func didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation(fromInterfaceOrientation: UIInterfaceOrientation) {
        if  fromInterfaceOrientation.isLandscape{
            
        }
        else if fromInterfaceOrientation.isPortrait{
            
        }

Comment: that still skews the view

Comment: shouldn't i be using a scroll view method